# Ubuntu 16.04 OpenVPN cannot access network

Tags: 16.04, vpn, openvpn

I have checked many posts related to OpenVPN issue but seems like I'm not able to put up proper search words to find a solution.

I have OpenVPN configuration using which I have setup VPN connection and manage to connect to VPN as I see a popup with message **VPN connection has been successfully established.** on both Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 16.04 machines.

On both Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 16.04 machines, I can access non VPN specific websites (gmail, stackoverflow) when connected to VPN (so assume it is not something related to Internet connectivity), but **I cannot access VPN specific resources i.e. web-portal and database on Ubuntu 16.04** which I can, on Ubuntu 14.04.

Checking other posts related to issue on Ubuntu 16.04, i checked

```
ip route
```

and found that there are two default shown on Ubuntu 16.04

```
default via 192.168.5.9 dev tun0  proto static  metric 50 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp6s0  proto static  metric 600
```

As per other post's advice, I checked *Use this connection only for resources on it network* under IPV4 settings->routes on Ubuntu 16.04.

After the above settings and connecting to VPN, when I do `IP route` on Ubuntu 16.04 i see

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp6s0  proto static  metric 600
```

I see my WiFi is marked as default connection instead of VPN connection (I assume VPN should be default route, as per IP route output on Ubuntu 14.04 machine.)

Ubuntu 14.04 `ip route` shows

```
default via 192.168.5.45 dev tun0  proto static
```

Comment: There's no need to redact [private network addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) in general. Please write your real IPs, as this is crucial information in this case to determine why it does not work.

Comment: @vidarlo added real IPs